# Create a dashboard-style site (not Wordpress dashboard) - is there a theme?

Tags: themes

Trying to figure out if there are any themes out there I could use to create a dashboard web site. (basically want to create something to point to all the ancillary services I use - backup, analytics, stock images, web host, etc.)

It is practically impossible to Google an answer - because once you use the term dashboard along with Wordpress every result refers to the Wordpress admin dashboard (whereas I'm just looking to create a site/page)

Anyone know of a dashboard-style theme?

Comment: Close-voted as **not a real question**: "*It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*" For one, a "dashboard-style site" is overly vague; and for another, WordPress can be used for just about **any** type of site design that displays managed content.

Comment: It's also a shopping question, hence my close vote

Comment: In case anyone ever wanders back in here...I finally found what I meant to ask for - they are called "Start Page" sites. Symbaloo.com is the one I decided on...but just searching for start page sites will get you lots of options.

Comment: Geckoboard it fantastic for these kind of things.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to head over to Themeforest.net and browse their wide selection of themes until you find something that's modular like.

Otherwise you could create a very simple theme your self as I assume you're going to be pulling in data from either RSS or API calls. You could effectively create the exact layout you want. This is what I have done as I didn't want any unnecessary, non-specific items associated with such ancillary services.

Hint: Look for Pinterest style themes or themes which make use of jQuery/Masonry layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged your question as wordpress.com, which means you're limited to the themes that WordPress.com has installed.

If you wish to install a different theme you must setup wordpress on your own server, otherwise feel free to browse the selection of themes provided.

Comment: Sorry...the wordpress.com tag was a mistake. Corrected in original post.

Comment: Ah then in that case, this is a 'shopping question' or a 'guessing game' for which there are rules for stack exchange sites.